# How to set any day/week/month as default view in zk-calendar?

Tags: zk, zk-calendar

I'm using **ZK CE-9.0.0** & **[zk-calendar-2.1.5 source code](https://www.zkoss.org/download/zkcalendar)**.

Whenever I open the calendar by default it displays today/current week/current month as per its mold. If I want to navigate to other day/week/month, I have to use the buttons provided.

[image: DefaultViewDay]

[image: DefaultViewWeek]

[image: DefaultViewMonth]

My requirement is, it should display the day/week/month specified by my program. Specified date can be in future or in past. That should be displayed by default. Can anyone tell me how can I achieve this?

Thanks,

RAS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZK Calendar can be initialized as explained on the first page (2nd paragraph) of [ZK Calendars Essentials](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Calendar%20Essentials/Working%20with%20ZK%20Calendar/Initializing%20View%20Attributes)

E.g. you can switch to the month view by calling:

```
calendars.setMold("month");
```

or specify a 7-days-view by calling:

```
calendars.setMold("default");
calendars.setDays(7);
```

The current date can be set by:

```
calendars.setCurrentDate(aDate);
```

Please also refer to the [zk calendar javadocs](https://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zkcal/org/zkoss/calendar/Calendars.html)

**UPDATE:**

Here a runnable piece of code setting the current date to something different than today using `setCurrentDate` (as mentioned above):

```
<?import java.text.*?>
<zk>
    <calendars id="cal"/>
    <zscript><![CDATA[
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        cal.setCurrentDate(sdf.parse("2019-01-14"));
        Clients.log("displaying from " + cal.getBeginDate() + " to " + cal.getEndDate());
    ]]></zscript>
</zk>
```

The calendar then shows the current week around this date. The same will happen for the month view. 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the question is not about how to initialize the calendar. It's also not about how to switch the calendar view. The question is about how to display some other day/week/month than current day/week/month, when the calendar is initialized. None of the links, you have posted, talk about that & also none of the code, you have posted, is fulfilling my requirement.

Comment: I updated my response, I hope I didn't mis-interpret your question again.